# No file or directory - Docker in Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-for-windows

A message is displayed when running the docker-compose up command

> /usr/bin/env: “bash\r” - No file or director

The volume is mounting normally, but it is not possible to run the ./run_web.sh file inside it.

## !/usr/bin/env bash

I find it inconsistent because when executing the command the docker already goes up and assembles the entire linux container.

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: "./"
      dockerfile: "./Dockerfile"
    container_name: "PRIJECT"
    command: ["./run_web.sh", '8010', 'enviroment', 'runserver']
    restart: "always"
    ports:  
      - "8010:8010"
    volumes:
      - "./../sistema_serverapp:/webapps"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: "banco_dados_default"
```

The command works perfectly on linux and mac.

I don't understand why it doesn't work on windows.

Could anyone help?

I am very grateful for everyone's attention.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

I open Shell Script file (run_web.sh) with VS Code, Change CRLF to LF, save it and then its work.

REF:
Create new file - default to LF, not CRLF 153
Configuring Line Separators 80